# jQuery scrollTop after insert data to div over AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to `scrollTop` `div` where I'm inserting to div data over AJAX. My divs looks like

```
<div id='desc10'>
</div>

<div class='scrollDown' data-id='10'>


<script>
    $("#desc10").html("hello<br />hello<br />");

    $(".scrollDown").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $("#desc"+id).stop().animate({
            scrollTop: "+=100"
        }, 100);
    });
</script>
```

But animation scrollTop doesn't work, show me no error.

Comment: Just to check, this isn't the only html on the page right? Cause this would be to little html to scroll in

Comment: No, it is multiple div like <div id='desc<?php echo $id; ?>'>

Comment: Don't know why this wont work, maybe it can count of height of that div after insert data over JavaScript

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not scrolling the CONTAINER of the divs

Comment: You should always use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) when adding event listeners to dynamically generated content.

Comment: What u mean? I'm scrolling that exactly div, where is content....

Comment: Jonathan - how can I use this Delegation? Can I use on('change').... ?

Comment: You'd use $(document).on('click','.scrollDown',function(){}) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use scrollTop, you should use it on the 'parent' div, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srwya791/)

So your code as it is 'works', it's just meaningless because desc10 isn't big enough to scroll in.

Instead, target whatever wraps desc10, and it works, as in the fiddle

```
$(".scrollDown").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

$("#container").stop().animate({
scrollTop: "+=100"
}, 100);
});
```

Comment: Here to help! If it fixed your problem, please accept it. @koca79331

Comment: I thinked about this solution, but I can't get it, why it must be parrent div?

Comment: @koca79331 Because scrollTop scrolls **inside** the element, not outside, so it puts the 'internal scrollbar' at the number you specify. If the element has nothing to scroll inside, you won't see any change. If you want to bring a certain element into view, you apply the scrollTop to whatever is holding the element